# operator+ and move semantics

Tags: c++, move, addition

How is the proper way to implement move semantics with `operator+`? Similarly to how it works for `std::string`?

I have attempted the following, however I was hoping there was some more elegant and possibly more correct way to do it:

```
class path
{
    std::vector<std::string> path_;
public:

    path& path::operator+=(const path& other)
    {
        path_.insert(std::begin(path_), std::begin(other.path_), std::end(other.path_));
        return *this;
    }

    path& path::operator+=(path&& other)
    {
        path_.insert(std::begin(path_), std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(other.path_)), std::make_move_iterator(std::end(other.path_)));
        return *this;
    }
};

template<typename L, typename R>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<path, L>::value, path>::type operator+(const L& lhs, const R& rhs)
{
    auto tmp = std::forward<L>(lhs);
    tmp     += std::forward<R>(rhs);
    return tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Way too complicated. :) Just abide by the rule you already should've followed:

- Take the lhs of `operator+` by value
- implement `operator+` in terms of `operator+=` on the lhs

This was already true in C++03, because of copy elision and RVO. The rule of thumb: If you make a copy anyways, make it in the parameters.

With that in mind:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>

class path
{
    std::vector<std::string> path_;
public:

    path& operator+=(path other)
    {
        auto op_begin = std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(other.path_));
        auto op_end = std::make_move_iterator(std::end(other.path_));
        path_.reserve(path_.size() + other.path_.size());
        path_.insert(std::end(path_), op_begin, op_end);
        return *this;
    }
};

path operator+(path lhs, path rhs)
{
  return std::move(lhs += std::move(rhs));
}
```

This should be the most optimal form. Note that I also changed your `operator+=` to actually *append* the path, and not prepend (I hope that's what you had in mind. If not, feel free to change it to `std::begin(path_)` again).

I also made the rhs of `operator+` and `operator+=` values and then just moved them around. `std::make_move_iterator` is also a nice utility. As the name implies, instead of copying, it moves the pointed-at elements. This should really be as fast as it's going to get.

Another version might be to use the iterator version of `std::move` in `operator+=`:

```
path& operator+=(path other)
{
    path_.reserve(path_.size() + other.path_.size());
    std::move(other.begin(), other.end(), std::back_inserter(path_));
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: This obviously isn't the most optimal form. If the LHS is an lvalue, you just redundantly copied it.

Comment: @DeadMG: Ehm.. `operator+` returns a new copy anyways. Where is the redundant copy I'm not seeing?

Comment: Aren't there any additional cases where lhs or rhs is an xvalue and can be re-used? (just an idea)

Comment: @Kos: If they are, they'll already be moved into the by-value parameters. I don't see how else you could reuse them.

Comment: @Xeo: Into the LHS of the operator. And indeed, in the RHS of the operator.