# Can I reuse an rvalue reference parameter to return an rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, rvalue-reference

Consider the following code:

```
struct MyString
{
  // some ctors

  MyString& operator+=( const MyString& other ); // implemented correctly
};

MyString operator+( const MyString& lhs, const MyString& rhs )
{
  MyString nrv( lhs );
  nrv += rhs;
  return nrv;
}

MyString&& operator+( MyString&& lhs, const MyString& rhs )
{
  lhs += rhs;
  return std::move( lhs ); // return the rvalue reference we received as a parameter!
}
```

This works for the following use-case

```
MyString a, b, c; // initialized properly
MyString result = a + b + c;
```

But it creates a dangling reference for

```
const MyString& result = a + b + c;
```

Now, I understand why that is and how to fix it (returning an ravlue instead of an rvalue reference) but I consider it a usage error if someone writes the above as the code looks like it is asking for trouble. Is there any "canonical" real-world example where the above operator returning a rvalue reference is a problem? What is a convincing reason why I should always return an rvalue from operators?

Comment: This issue was also brought up in [Defect report 1138](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#1138).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The example you are looking for is a **range-based `for` statement**:

```
MyString a, b, c;
for( MyCharacter mc : a + b + c ) { ... }
```

In this case the result of `a + b + c` is bound to a reference, but the nested temporary (generated by `a + b` and returned as an rvalue reference by `(a + b) + c`) is destroyed before the range-based for loop is executed.

The standard defines range-based for loops in

> #### 6.5.4 The range-based for statement [stmt.ranged]
>
> <sup>1</sup> For a range-based `for` statement of the form
>
> `for (`*for-range-declaration*`:`*expression*`)`*statement*
>
> let *range-init* be equivalent to the *expression* surrounded by parentheses
>
> `( expression )`
>
> and for a range-based `for` statement of the form
>
> `for (`*for-range-declaration*`:`*braced-init-list*`)`*statement*
>
> let *range-init* be equivalent to the *braced-init-list*. In each case, a range-based `for` statement is equivalent to
>
> ```
> {
>    auto && __range = range-init;
>    for ( auto __begin = begin-expr,
>               __end = end-expr;
>          __begin != __end;
>          ++__begin ) {
>       for-range-declaration = *__begin;
>       statement
>    }
> }
> ```

Note that `auto && __range = range-init;` would extend the lifetime of a temporary returned from *range-init*, but it does not extend the lifetime of nested temporaries *inside* of *range-init*.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of asking for trouble, you should trust the string's own move constructor:

```
MyString operator+(MyString lhs, MyString rhs)
{
    lhs += std::move(rhs);
    return std::move(lhs);
}
```

Now both `MyString x = a + b;` and `MyString y = MyString("a") + MyString("b");` work efficiently.

Comment: For `x = a + b`, an extra copy of `b` is created which is not needed. But as I said, I know how to fix it, the question was why returning an rvalue reference is a problem.

Comment: @DanielFrey: Yeah, I guess, one of the two could be a reference... Returning a reference is only OK if you can guarantee that the reference refers to something that exists, which is hard and non-obvious for the user.

Comment: @DanielFrey: Since appending at the front is presumably not worth optimizing, I'd probably change the second parameter only to a `const MyString &`, as you have in your original code.

Comment: @DanielFrey Passing by value instead of by reference was presented at [Going Native 2012 - STL11 Magic && Secrets](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/STL11-Magic-Secrets) starting at the `35:10` mark. It's worth watching if you haven't seen it.