# Symmetric operator+ in terms of operator+= in modern C++?

Tags: gcc, clang, operators, nrvo

I was reading this note on the implementation of symmetric operators in Boost.Operator https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/utility/operators.htm#symmetry and I suspect it is awfully outdated.

The discussion revolves on what is the best way to implement `operator+` generically, if a consistent `operator+=` is available. The conclusion there is that it is (was),

```
T operator+( const T& lhs, const T& rhs ){
   T nrv( lhs ); nrv += rhs; return nrv;
}
```

because at the time some compilers supported NRVO, as opposed to RVO.

Now, <s>with NRVO being mandatory, and</s>  all sorts of optimization being performed, is this still the case?

For example other version that may make sense now for certain cases is:

```
    T operator+(T lhs, const T& rhs ){
       T ret(std::move(lhs)); ret += rhs; return ret;
    }
```

or

```
    T operator+(T lhs, const T& rhs ){
      lhs += rhs; return lhs;
    }
```

Given a class that has a constructor, a move constructor, and reasonable `operator+=`. For example:

```
#include<array>
#include<algorithm>

using element = double; // here double, but can be more complicated
using array = std::array<double, 9>; // here array, but can be more complicated

array& operator+=(array& a, array const& b){
    std::transform(begin(a), end(a), begin(b), begin(a), [](auto&& x, auto&& y){return x + y;});
    return a;
}
array& operator+=(array&& a, array const& b){
    std::transform(begin(a), end(a), begin(b), begin(a), [](auto&& x, auto&& y){return x + std::move(y);});
    return a;
}
```

What is the best way to implement a symmetric `operator+`? Here is a set of possible codes

```
/*1*/ array sum(array const& a, array const& b){array tmp(a); tmp+=b; return tmp;} // need operator+= and copy-constructor
/*2*/ array sum(array const& a, array const& b){return array(a)+=b;} // needs operator+= && and copy-constructor
/*3*/ array sum(array a, array const& b){return std::move(a)+=b;} // needs operator+= && and can use move-constructor
/*4*/ array sum(array a, array const& b){array tmp(std::move(a)); tmp+=b; return tmp;} // needs operator+= and can use move-constructor
```

I tried it in https://godbolt.org/z/2YPhcg and just by counting the number of assembly lines, which all other things being equal might tell what is the best implementation. I get these mixed results:

```
| code       | gcc -O2     | clang  -O2   |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| /*1*/      |   33 lines  |     64 lines |
| /*2*/      |   39 lines  |     59 lines |
| /*3*/      |   33 lines  |     62 lines |
| /*4*/      |   33 lines  |     64 lines |
```

While `/*3*/` and `/*4*/` can benefit from calls of the form `sum(std::move(a), b)` or even `sum(sum(a, c), b)`.

**So is `T tmp(a); tmp+=b; return tmp;` still the best way to implement `operator+(T [const&], T const&)`?**

It looks like if there is a move constructor and a moving +=, there are other possibilities but only seem to produce simpler assembly in clang.

Comment: NRVO is not mandatory

Comment: In the bolded text you ask specifically about one signature of `operator+` whereas in the preceding text you allow different signatures,  please clarify

Comment: @M.M well, I am interested in the behavior, not in the signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the signature is:

```
T operator+(T const& a, T const& b )
```

(as you say in the bolded question text), then the body should be:

```
return T(a) += b;
```

where the *result object* is the only `T` constructed. The version `T nrv( lhs ); nrv += rhs; return nrv;` theoretically risks the compiler not merging `nrv` with the *result object*.

---

Note that the above signature does not allow moving out of any of the arguments. If it's desirable to move out of the lhs, then this seems optimal to me:

```
T operator+(T const& a, T const& b)
{
    return T(a) += b;
}

T operator+(T&& a, T const& b)
{
    return T(std::move(a)) += b;
}
```

In both cases the *result object* is guaranteed to be the only object constructed. In the "classic" version taking `T a`, then the case of an rvalue argument would incur an extra move.

If you want to move out of the right-hand side then two more overloads can be added :)

Note that I have not considered the case of returning `T&&` for [reasons described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226150/can-i-reuse-an-rvalue-reference-parameter-to-return-an-rvalue-reference)

Comment: I don't get the relation to the linked question exactly can you lay it out?

Comment: @alfC I'm saying I don't think it would be a good idea to do `T&& operator+(...stuff...)`

Comment: Yes, I don't know I have been using lvalue references for a while and I still don't understand what does it means to return T&&.

Comment: Technically, if the operation is commutative, as `+` should be (well except for `std::string`, using `+` for std::string was a mistake), then one can implement this for all the combinations an permuntations of `T&`, `T const&`, `T&&` (9 combinations). Also there is a hidden assumption here that I realize, this is not universal, it only applies for "value types" since `T(a)` is supposed to create an independent copy. (i.e. reference-like types will not behave well.)

Comment: I edited to use `T const&` instead of `T&`; there would only be at most 4 permutations.  Whether or not moving out of the r.h.s. is useful depends on the properties of the class. (E.g. for `std::string` there's nothing to be gained by moving out of both operands)

Comment: ah, yes that makes sense.

Comment: In the second case, what would be the difference with using     `return std::move(a) += b;`?

Comment: @alfC that would be the same as `return a += b;`, i.e. call `a.operator+=` to update `a` in-place , but then it would copy-construct the *result object* from `a` because `operator+=` returns an lvalue reference.